# Can eight circles be constructed from three circles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given three sufficiently spaced circles in a plane, is it possible, using a straight edge and compass, to construct the eight circles that are tangent to all three given circles?

Comment: That's an interesting question. Do you have any thoughts on it of your own? For example some special cases?

Comment: This is known as  [Problem of Apollonius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius). In around 1816, [Joseph Diaz Gergonne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Diaz_Gergonne) using some symmetry inherit in the Apollonius problem created a compass and straightedge only constructions for the eight circles. Don't ask me for details because I don't know. Please read the wiki entry and follow the references there.

Comment: Ultimately I want to find a "magic" function that would that would send nine pieces of information: the coordinates of the center of each circle and the radii, to produce an output of twenty-four  pieces of information: the coordinates of the center of the circles and the radii.

Comment: Thank you for the link to Joseph Diaz Gergonne.

Comment: @Robert: Your question asks for constructions, but your later comment indicates that you just want centers and radii. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I have both questions in mind. I was hoping that the solution to one might lead me to the answer of the other.

Answer (score -3):

yes, one outside all of them, one inside all of them, three inside one of them, and three inside two of them. As the question was edited, previously the three circles were of the same size and their centroids were concentric. the general case of three circles in space of arbitrary size and position is not always possible.

four of these circles are of significance, the rest can be obtained by rotations. One circle that is tangential to the outside of the circles, on that is tangential to the inside of all the circles. these two cannot be rotated to obtain more permutations. if you construct a circle that is tangential to the inside of ONE of the circles and the outside of the other two circles it can be rotated in space to obtain two more. if you construct a circle that is tangential to the inside of TWO of the circles and tangential to the outside of one, this can be rotated to obtain the remaining two.

Comment: Thank you. I know the eight circles exist, but how can you be sure they can be constructed?

Comment: Are you sure they exist? There are plenty of counter-examples. Perhaps you could rephrase your question to ask under what circumstances can three circles be constructed so that eight circles are tangent to them, and in which case how can you construct the eight circles?

Comment: I think that you missed the "*...using a straight edge and compass...*" part of OP's question.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I was afraid to ask for too much. I know there are situations in which the three circles could generate as few as one circle to be tangent to the other three.

Comment: @mapierce271 please give an example of a circle that exists and can be described as I have above in my answer that cannot be constructed, ie: drawn with a strait edge and a compass. I am curious.

Comment: Since you posted the answer, the burden of proving that your circles can be constructed with straightedge and compass in on you.